# Editing multiple text files in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, documentclass-writing, multiple-files

I'm working on a class file in Overleaf, and would like to be able to have the editing tab for the class file and the main file open at the same time, rather than needing to repeatedly switch between them.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can have two browser tabs open, one for the document and one for the class

Comment: as @DavidCarlisle is saying, just use two tabs. But be aware, that you can't compile in both tabs at the same time.

Comment: Ah so I could have two tabs open, and then use a split screen to have each tab visible at the same time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Copy the project link into different tabs and select each file in each tab, then, you will be able to use the navigator shortcuts to change between tabs. When you select a file in a tab, this selection doesn't affect the file selected in the other tabs.

Comment: I think more what I was going for is to have both of them visible at the same time, but I think the separate tabs idea should work if I use a split screen to see them both at the same time.  Thank you!